# Updating a column by using CASE expression throwing ERROR: column "external_uuid" is of type uuid but expression is of type boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case, coalesce

I have a table where I would like to do update a column `external_uuid` only if that column already doesn't have a value:

```
private const val updateSql = """
  update customer
  set
      external_id = :externalId,
      external_uuid = CASE when external_uuid is null then external_uuid = :externalUuid END,
      name = :name,
      address = :address,
      zip_code = :zipCode,
      zip_area = :zipArea,
      country_code = :countryCode,
      is_deleted = :markedForRemoval
  where is_deleted = false AND (external_uuid = :externalUuid OR (external_id = :externalId AND external_subcustomer = :subCustomer))
"""
```

But, if I do an update like that I get an error:

```
 ERROR: column "external_uuid" is of type uuid but expression is of type boolean
```

How can I conditionally set only one column on an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression returns the result of this boolean expression:

```
external_uuid = :externalUuid
```

which may be `true` or `false` and can't be stored in a column defined as `uuid` and this is why you get the error.

You should write it like this:

```
external_uuid = CASE when external_uuid is null then :externalUuid else external_uuid END
```

or:

```
external_uuid = coalesce(external_uuid, :externalUuid)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can I just ask you why doesn't the update work when I update it with the same value that it has, so for example, if I have ```set external_uuid = :externalUuid```, I get an error: ```ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint, Key external_uuid already exists```. That happens when I am updating a row where the uuid matches existing uuid, but if I use ```coalesce(external_uuid, :externalUuid)``` it works. How come the former doesn't work when in both cases the column is updated with the same value, or does coalesce not update it the column is not null?

Comment: no, I didn't mean the CASE expression, just directly setting ```external_uuid = :externalUuid```, how is that different from ```coalesce(external_uuid, :externalUuid)```if the value you are updating with is the same as existing value in the DB? Why is that throwing ```unique constraint error``` and ```coalesce()``` is not?

Comment: @Ludwig are you sure that `:externalUuid` has the exact same value as the row it updates? If yes, can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3bbebf7efe9f01901d41d4013bf96b4c